# Lost access to wp-admin and some of user meta-data

Tags: wordpress

We are running into the same problem for the third time already. Suddenly all the users, including admins, lose their access to wp-admin, plus some custom user fields get erased.

When I look into the database, it looks like user roles are not changed (admin is still admin). So why I can't access the backend is not clear.

Every time we recover from the backup, but it becomes a regular problem.

I can't figure out if it's a WordPress, a plugin, a hosting issue or we get hacked every time it happens. The problem is that the logs on the hosting stopped being recorded on the 4th of October (we'll be changing hosting as it's the second time I see the logs not recorded).

For the guest users the site is working fine.

My question is: where to look for the source of the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Regularly update your wordpress and plugins. I read somewhere wordpress contaminates sites if not updated regularly. So whenever you see an update for a plugin or core files do not forget to hit that.

Comment: That's not easy for a system that was totally custom built. I can't just hit the update immediately, I need to test on a separate system that the updates are not faulty. Otherwise I risk to break something, which happened a couple of times already. But thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking it's somehow related but was not sure.

Answer (score 0):

A friend asked me to help him with a similar problem ... somehow a part of the usermeta table was lost yesterday and today. This is a list of the plugins that he's using ... maybe there's a match somewhere:

- Akismet anti-spam
- Autoptimize
- Cherry Data Importer
- Cherry Data Importer
- Cherry PopUps
- Cherry Search
- Cherry Sidebars
- Cherry Socialize
- Cookie Notice
- Duplicate Page
- Editor clasic
- Contact Form 7
- Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights
- Mashshare Share Buttons
- Mobile Menu
- Post Types Order
- Post Views Counter
- Q2W3 Post Order
- SSL Insecure Content Fixer
- WordPress Social Login
- Yoast SEO

Thankfully we have a backup and were able to restore the usermeta data, but since it happened twice by now, the problem persists :(

WP and all plugins are updated.

Comment: Out of all the plugins you listed we only use Yoast. Are you saying they were all updated when it happened? I was thinking it somehow related to not updating in time, as the previous reply suggested.

Comment: When did it happen for the first time? If it happens at the same time for your friend and for us, the reason might me external. For us it was yesterday, and previously - beginning of this month and beginning of September. @TIG

Comment: It happened on the 17, 24, 25 and twice today, on 29 October ... I'm going to disable all non-critical plugins and keep you posted.

And yes, all plugins + wp are updated.

Comment: Wow that's intense. We didn't have it since the day I posted here. I will really appreciate you updating me if you find the reasons somehow. Thanks and good luck. @TIG

Comment: I've uninstalled the plugins: Autoptimize, Cherry Data Importer, Cherry Data Importer, Cherry PopUps, Cherry Search, Cherry Sidebars, Cherry Socialize, WordPress Social Login and so far it works fine. No lost usermeta data :-)